# How to parse XML string with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, json, prototypejs

I have a string `<ul><li e="100" n="50">Foo</li><li e="200" n="150">Bar</li></ul>` and on client side I have to convert it to JSON. Something like `{data:['Foo','Bar'],params:['100;50','200;150']}`

I found a pretty good way to achieve it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084411/223610) so my code should be something like that

```
var $input = $(input);
var data = "data:[";
var params = "params:[";

var first = true;
$input.find("li").each(function() {
    if (!first) {
        data += ",";
        params += ",";
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
    data += "'" + $(this).text() + "'";
    var e = $(this).attr("e");
    var n = $(this).attr("n");
    params += "'" + e + ';' + n + "'";
});

return "{data + "]," + params + "]}";
```

But the problem is that I can't use jquery. How can I do the same thing with prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a DOM parser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser

Something like this...

```
var xmlStr = '<ul><li e="100" n="50">Foo</li><li e="200" n="150">Bar</li></ul>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "application/xml");

var rootElement = doc.documentElement;
var children = rootElement.childNodes;

var jsonObj = {
    data: [],
    params: []
};

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    // I realize this is not how your implementation is, but this should give
    // you an idea of how to work on the DOM element
    jsonObj.data.push( children[i].getAttribute('e') );
    jsonObj.params.push( children[i].getAttribute('n') );
}

return jsonObj.toJSON();
```

Also, don't manually build your JSON string. Populate an object, then [JSON-encode](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/toJSON/) it.

Edit: Note that you need to test for DOMParser before you can use it. Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp) for how you can do that. Sorry for the W3Schools link.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are building an array object with string? Why not

```
var data = new Array();
var params = new Array();

$$("li").each(function() {
    data.push ($(this).text());
    params.psuh($(this).attr("e") + ";" + $(this).attr("n"));
});


return {data:data.toString(), params:params.toString()};
```

or

```
return {data:data, params:params};
```

Comment: Yes, but it still requires jQuery and I can use only PrototypeJS

Comment: Try using $$, Here is a reference for it: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/ $$('div') === document.getElementsByName('div')

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem.