# Parsing XML Text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, parsing

I'm working with a database that has X and Y points per group, it's being used to draw outlines of images.

Right now in my web side this code is what I use to get the points:

```
var Drawing = $(XML).find('DrawingXML');

alert($(Drawing[1]).text());
```

Result:

```
 <DrawingPoints>
   <Point><X>1</X><Y>2</Y></Point>
   <Point><X>2</X><Y>4</Y></Point>
   <Point><X>3</X><Y>5</Y></Point>
   <Point><X>2</X><Y>2</Y></Point>
   <Point><X>0</X><Y>4</Y></Point>
 </DrawingPoints>
```

Using the .replace() call only changes one item so it's usable for something like this:

```
.replace("</DrawingPoints>","");
```

but if I want to replace all 'Point' tags I'm out of luck.

My goal is to use the canvas feature to draw the points out so I want it to be parsed like this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(1,2);
ctx.lineTo(2,4);
ctx.lineTo(3,5);
ctx.lineTo(2,2);
ctx.lineTo(0,4);
ctx.stroke();
```

I'm not going to use this with IE browsers just Safari/Chrome, if that helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Get all your X and Y values at once:

```
var points = {};
points.X = Array();
points.Y = Array();
var ix = 0;

$(XML).find('DrawingXML DrawingPoints Point X').each(function()
{
    points.X[ix++] = $(this).text();
});
$(XML).find('DrawingXML DrawingPoints Point Y').each(function()
{
    points.Y[ix++] = $(this).text();
});
```

This might not be exact, I didn't test it and my Javascript is a bit rusty, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is find works for 'DrawingXML' but DrawingPoints > Point > Y all of those "XML" items are kept in text they're not actually XML if that makes sense... if there was a way via jquery to convert the text into XML and then do that... that'd be great.

Comment: If you load that string into jquery, you will have the objects to search and loop through it.

Comment: jQuery can parse any markup, be it XML, XHTML, or HTML. Feed your entier XML structure into jQuery so it can do its magic. If you can't figure out how to actually get your XML as a string, that's probably another, separate question. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll probably save an awful lot of brainache by using a library instead of writing your own code.

I reckon [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) does what you need:

- [d3.xml](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_xml)
- [d3.geo.path](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-_path)

Comment: That seems interesting, and I may use it if I get no solutions.  It's just I'm new to programming in general, and looking at a new library is way over my head.

Comment: I'd argue that libraries are the best way to learn - you can see how to design an approach to the problem and check the source for specific implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question/answer. It's not Prototype specific and should help you here.

[How to parse XML string with Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840196/how-to-parse-xml-string-with-prototype/9843012#9843012)