# How to bind xml to div element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a xml url, need to bind the same xml(with out changing the xml format)  to a div element using jquery ajax call. Please find my smaple code below

```
   <div class="json-full-output">
   <pre></pre>
   </div>



        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
              url:APIUrl,
              dataType: "xml" ,
              success: function (xml) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                     $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                $(".json-full-output pre").append($xml);
            },
         });
```

Comment: How about simply: `$(".json-full-output pre").text(xml);`?

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: Nagarraju.. it is not binding any thing in UI

Comment: try this if you find solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889688/how-to-query-an-xml-string-via-dom-in-jquery

Comment: acdcjunior .... if I used above code it is showing  [object XMLDocument] in UI

Comment: put console statements and check if your jQuery Ajax works

Comment: Nagaraju... it is JqueryAjax working fine, only problem with binding xmldoc object to div element is issue

Answer (score 0):

To show the xml without changing it format. In ajax method change the data type from "xml" to "text", and in success method directly display the xml data without converting into xml object, and also use 'text' method to display the content instead of 'append'.  Please try the below code.

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                //url: "/ModelDesigner/GetFullXmlDataObjectForModel",
                url:APIUrl,
               // data: params,
                dataType: "text" ,
               // async: false,
                success: function (xml) {
                    console.log(xml);
                    /*var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                         $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                        */ 
                    $(".json-full-output pre").text(xml);
                },
               //contentType: 'application/json'
            });
```

Comment: thanks shanmugasuresh.P . It is binding now, but it is not showing in a xml format... all tags are merged and showing In a single file...